# I have a program where I need to user will be asked if they want to continue and add to the sum each time

Tags: java

Write a java program to do a series sum. It is
considered that the inter term difference (i.e. common difference) is
always 1.

Example: If the first term and the last term of the series is 5 and 10
respectively then the series is: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

To complete this task, you should have the knowledge of following java
programming topics:

- Taking input from keyboard i.e. java IO
- Java loops.

User Specification: User will provide two integer numbers i.e. First term and last
term.

Constraints: first term should be between 1 to 100 and last term
must be greater than first term.

- Program will display only the sum of the series.
- At last, user will be asked for the series sum continuation.

Sample of final output

It is a simple Series sum problem. Prepared by Your Name

```
Enter first term between 1 to 100: 4
Enter last term: 4
Error: Enter an integer greater than 4: 1
Error: Enter an integer greater than 4: 6
SUM = 15
Do you like to do again?
(Press 'y' for 'Yes' and 'n' for 'No') y
Enter first term between 1 to 100: 1
Enter last term: 10
SUM = 55
Do you like to do again?
(Press 'y' for 'Yes' and 'n' for 'No') n
```

```
package lab3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = null;
        int term = 0;
        int lastTerm = 0;
        int sum = 0;
System.out.println("It is a simple series sum problem. Prepared by -------");
        System.out.println("Enter first term between 1 to 100:");
        term = input.nextInt();
        while (term < 0 || term > 100) {
            System.err.print("Error: Enter the first term between 1 to 100");
            term = input.nextInt();


        }
        System.out.println("Enter last term:");
        lastTerm = input.nextInt();
        while (lastTerm <= term) {
            System.err.print("Error: Enter an integer greater than " +  term);
            lastTerm = input.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = term+1; i<lastTerm; i++) {
            sum += term + lastTerm + i;
            System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
        }

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Do you like to do again");
            userInput = input.next();
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

            else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

Need to be able to repeat the questions add to get that total of 55.
```

Mark thanks for your help so far its close to working this now what it is outputting

```
Enter first term between 1 to 100:
4
Enter last term:
6
Sum:4
Sum:9
Sum:15
Do you like to do again
y
It is a simple series sum problem. Prepared by -------
Enter first term between 1 to 100:
1
Enter last term:
10
Sum:16
Sum:18
Sum:21
Sum:25
Sum:30
Sum:36
Sum:43
Sum:51
Sum:60
Sum:70
Do you like to do again
```

Comment: So... what is the problem for your homework?

Comment: I dont know how to continue it properly to ask the questions all over again and then add it again, example you put 4 and 6 the series is 4 5 6 . 4 + 5 + 6 = 15 and then  ask the user to continue and then it adds the series again and adds it to 15.

Comment: By reading your sample of final output, i would suggest you to move most of your code in the main function to a separated function, so that you can call that new function again and again to do the addition whenever the user has entered 'Y' in your while loop

Comment: @CHIKA: Please [edit] your post above to include an actual and specific question. The key parts of the question should not be comments but should be easily found within your question proper.

Comment: Just read your output, the problem is you should reset the sum back to 0 if the user entered 'Y'. 70 - 15 = 55, which is the sum of 1 to 10

Comment: Ya i just was calculating it cause i did not make sense so i it pretty much just has to clear the value and repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's problem is this. It is located below the code. The question needs formatting since the OP's problem description is included in the code snippet.

> Need to be able to repeat the questions add to get that total of 55.

```
String userInput = null;
        int term = 0;
        int lastTerm = 0;
        int sum = 0;
System.out.println("It is a simple series sum problem. Prepared by -------");
        System.out.println("Enter first term between 1 to 100:");
        term = input.nextInt();
        while (term < 0 || term > 100) {
            System.err.print("Error: Enter the first term between 1 to 100");
            term = input.nextInt();


        }
        System.out.println("Enter last term:");
        lastTerm = input.nextInt();
        while (lastTerm <= term) {
            System.err.print("Error: Enter an integer greater than " +  term);
            lastTerm = input.nextInt();
        }
        // Edit start
        for (int i = term; i<=lastTerm; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
        // Edit end
```

Put the above code inside this while loop.

```
        while (true) {
            // Place it here
            System.out.println("Do you like to do again");
            Boolean willContiue = false;
            while (true){
                userInput = input.next();
                if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
                    willContiue = true;
                    break;
                else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!willContinue) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

By doing the above modifications you will now get the user to input his choice again. Since in your code you are just asking the user if he/she would like to do it again, and if the user answers "Y" your code does not do anything. That is why the question does not repeat.

Comment: I think there is also a problem whith my for loop I put the actually stuff inside the while loop and it does now work with continuation but I get this when I enter 1 and 10

Comment: It is a simple series sum problem. Prepared by -------
Enter first term between 1 to 100:
1
Enter last term:
10
Sum:13
Sum:27
Sum:42
Sum:58
Sum:75
Sum:93
Sum:112
Sum:132
Do you like to do again

Comment: @CHIKA I have edited my answer, refer to the edited parts. You're previous code is incorrect since it is adding also the lastTerm and the term. Adding just the variable "i" will suffice.

Comment: its still doing the same thing it prints sum more then once and it sill wont even add to 50

Comment: @CHIKA just place the system.outPrint outside the sum calculation. (See updated code above) Also can you comment your input and result

Comment: its working perfectly now just added before the program continues sum to equal to 0, thanks for your help really appreciated.

Comment: @CHIKA I am glad you have made it work. Do not forget to mark my answer as the accepted answer, so that this question will be closed. :)